# How to destroy a button widget that was placed in an if condition? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I couldn't word my question well but here's some context.

I created a button in tkinter and I used `.place(x, y)` inside an if condition but now I want to destroy it if another condition is met. It doesn't get destroyed even if the second condition is met. Please help.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

button = Button(window, text='Button')

x = 10 
y = 10 # just imagine that y became 5 at some point

if x == 10:
    button.place(x=0, y=0)

elif y == 5:
    button.destroy() 

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If this is working as it is written, make sure the condition that created the button is no longer True. The button is getting created and destroyed constantly.

Comment: Even if y would become 5 at some point, x is still 10, so the button will be placed and the second if statement is an elif so it will never be run as long as x is 10.

Comment: I see, just as Nicolas said, I should set the condition that placed the button to False but I'm completely blank and I want to create the button only if the condition is met.. How would I do that?

Comment: Did you mean: `if y == 5:`?

Comment: It's actually just `y == 10` but just imagine that it reached 5 at some point. It's just an example.

Comment: You need to update your question with a minimum viable example. Currently nothing really happens before the last line and once the last line is executing nothing else can happen whilst `tkinter` is in control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you want to accomplish here, but you seem to be misunderstanding how if-elif-else works. It is intended to give alternatives for the values of the same variable, or in any case, both possibilities shouldn't be possible to happen simultaneously to get the desired outcome. Elif is short for "else if", meaning that it's evaluated only if the "if" statement is false.

In your case, x is already equal to 10 and you aren't changing it at any point, so the "if" condition is always fulfilled and the code never gets to the "elif" statement.

If y is changing and reaches 5, you could change the "elif" statement into "if" and add the condition that y has to be not equal to 5 when creating the button (otherwise, it will constantly create and destroy itself).

Also, as your current code works, there is no loop running. The code evaluates only once.

If I understand what you want to do, it's something along these lines.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
x = IntVar()
y = IntVar()

x.set(10)
y.set(10)

button = Button(window, text='Button', command=lambda: y.set(5))


def loop_this():

    if (x.get() == 10) and (y.get() != 5):
        button.place(x=0, y=0)

    if y.get() == 5:
        button.destroy()

    window.after(1000, loop_this)


loop_this()

window.mainloop()
```

In general, it's good to use Tkinter variables (IntVar, StringVar, BoolVar) when working with Tkinter. To replicate a scenario where y = 5, I made it be equal to 5 when the button is pressed, but it can be changed elsewhere in the code and it will work in the same way.
The main thing is to put the thing into a function, attach it to the main window and run it in a loop. To do that we use `.after(time_in_miliseconds_between_loops, function_to_loop_without_brackets)`

and call the function before `window.mainloop()`.
Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: It worked after some adjustments. Thanks.